# Hide Primeng datatable paginator when no records

Tags: angular, primeng

I have added Datatable from primeng-v2.0.4.

```
<p-dataTable 
    [value]="tableData" 
    [rows]="rows" 
    [paginator]="true" 
    [resizableColumns]="true"
    [tableStyleClass]="table-wrap" 
    [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
  :
  :
</p-dataTable>
```

I saw option `[paginatorAlwaysVisible]="false"` in one of the forums, but that attribute does not seem to be available for this version of primeng.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a method "isPaginatorVisible(): boolean" on your component that checks weather there are records or not.
Then just bind the property [paginator]="isPaginatorVisible()" to the p-dataTable.

Comment: Great One! How could I miss it! Thanks :)

Comment: This solution didn't work when "filter" is used altogether.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Primeng version 7.0.5 try this,

`[alwaysShowPaginator]="false"`